# List variables in equation

Tags: horizontal-alignment

My code looks horrendous

```
When monochromatic light is shone through a solution of iron, Beer's law states that 

$$ A = \varepsilon l c $$
\begin{tabular}{l}
      Where $A$ is amount of light absorbed \\
      \quad \quad  \quad $\varepsilon$ is the molar absorbance coefficient, which varies with wavelength,\\
      \quad \quad  \quad but not with concentration\\
      \quad  \quad \quad $l$ is the thickness of the sample

\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Can it be improved?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There are many improvements possible, for example not using $$...$$ and a description list, for example

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please have a look on [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to), the description of the variables can be done in `description` or in an `itemize` list, for example.

From a personal point of view, I would rather use `\ell` instead of `l` as equation identifier.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
When monochromatic light is shone through a solution of iron, Beer's law states that 

\[ A = \varepsilon l c \]

\noindent where
\begin{description}
\item  $A$ is amount of light absorbed 
\item  $\varepsilon$ is the molar absorbance coefficient, which varies with wavelength,\\
  but not with concentration
\item  $l$ is the thickness of the sample
\end{description}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Another (better?) solution, with more fine control of the list parameters, better optical appealance, but this is a matter of taste actually.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
When monochromatic light is shone through a solution of iron, Beer's law states that 

\[ A = \varepsilon \ell c \]

\noindent where
\begin{description}
\item $A$   is amount of light absorbed 
\item  $\varepsilon$ is the molar absorbance coefficient, which varies with wavelength,\\
  but not with concentration
\item  $\ell$ is the thickness of the sample
\end{description}


\noindent where
\begin{description}[labelindent=10pt,labelsep=10pt]
\item[$A$]   is amount of light absorbed 
\item[$\varepsilon$] is the molar absorbance coefficient, which varies with wavelength,\\
  but not with concentration
\item[$\ell$] is the thickness of the sample
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it works for me. What font did you use? it looks nicer than \usepackage{mathpazo}

Comment: Since I did not use any other package apart from `mathtools` I would assume it's the standard font, CM math in the ams version?

Comment: If for no other reason than to avoid attracting @egreg's lightning bolt and zap, you shouldn't leave blank lines before and after the displayed equation. Syntactically speaking, the displayed equation is part of the paragraph; don't have TeX insert unnecessary (and typographically speaking inferior) paragraph breaks.

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative is to use a `(d)cases` environment:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

  When monochromatic light is shone through a solution of iron, Beer's law states that
  \[ A = \varepsilon l c ,\quad
    \text{where }\quad
    \begin{dcases*}
        A& is amount of light absorbed \\
        \varepsilon& is the molar absorbance coefficient, which varies \\
                   & with wavelength but not with concentration\\
        l& is the thickness of the sample
  \end{dcases*}
  \]

\end{document}
```

Of course, you could ust use an ordinary `cases` environment but I prefer `dcases` from the [mathtools](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package.

Comment: Typographically speaking, a shortcoming of this solution is that all interline distances to the right of the large curly brace are the same. This isn't quite right because lines 2 and 3 belong together; hence, their interline distance should be slightly smaller than that between lines 1&2 and lines 3&4.

Comment: @Mico Would it be easy to remove the space between the second and third line?

Comment: @jack - The cleanest way to remove the space would be to use a `\parbox` construct, as I do in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Two tricky examples (your code at the beginning):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

When monochromatic light is shone through a solution of iron, Beer's law states that 

$$ A = \varepsilon l c $$
\begin{tabular}{l}
      Where $A$ is amount of light absorbed \\
      \quad \quad  \quad $\varepsilon$ is the molar absorbance coefficient, which varies with wavelength,\\
      \quad \quad  \quad but not with concentration\\
      \quad  \quad \quad $l$ is the thickness of the sample
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

When monochromatic light is shone through a solution of iron, Beer's law states that 
\[
 A = \varepsilon l c 
\]
 Where $A$ is amount of light absorbed 

\noindent\hangindent3em\hangafter0
      $\varepsilon$ is the molar absorbance coefficient, which varies with wavelength,\\
     but not with concentration\\
       $l$ is the thickness of the sample



When monochromatic light is shone through a solution of iron, Beer's law states that 
\[
 A = \varepsilon l c 
\]
Where $A$ is amount of light absorbed \\
 \hspace*{3em}%     
\begin{tabular}{l}
$\varepsilon$ is the molar absorbance coefficient, which varies with wavelength,\\
       but not with concentration\\
       $l$ is the thickness of the sample
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution, which uses an `align*` environment. Its virtue, so to speak, is that the left-hand edges of the main equation and of the description lines are aligned. Two reasons for using a `\parbox` for the description of `\varepsilon`: (i) no need to select a line break by hand, and (ii) the interline spacing inside the parbox won't be as wide as across the other lines of the `align*` environment. The only choice that needs to be made is the width of the parbox -- I happened to select `3in`, but you should feel free to adjust this to suit your needs.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,ragged2e}

\begin{document}
When monochromatic light is shone through a solution of iron, Beer's law states that 
\begin{align*}
A &= \varepsilon l c
\shortintertext{where}
A &\text{ is the amount of light absorbed,}\\
\varepsilon &\text{ \parbox[t]{3in}{\RaggedRight is the molar absorbance coefficient, which 
   varies with wavelength but not with concentration, and}}\\
l &\text{ is the thickness of the sample.}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps but this is how usually I do what yo asks:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{amsmath}    

\begin{document}
When monochromatic light is shone through a solution of iron, Beer's law states that:

\begin{equation*} % The starred version avoid the automatic number.
 A = \varepsilon l c
 \end{equation*} 

\noindent Where:\\ 
$A$ is amount of light absorbed, \\
$\varepsilon$ is the molar absorbance coefficient, which varies with wavelength, but not with concentration, and\\
$l$ is the thickness of the sample.
\end{document}
```

[image]

I use `amsmath`for use the starred version of `equation` environment that produces the same than `equation` but the number of the equation. I don't use the `tabular` environment, and the alignment is very simple. It works for you?

Comment: never leave a blank line before a displayed equation (it produces an empty paragraph that looks like vertical space but does not work correctly at page breaks) similarly it would be better not to have the blank line after, then you would not need `\noindent`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for that suggestion, I'll take it in account.